# custom render connected react component with mock axios response - getBy* query misleading exception

Tags: react-redux, react-testing-library

I have a problem with updating props in my test after some code refactor. I use custom render and mock axios request but my component doesn't rerender (?). In my component in async ComponentDidMount() I do POST request. When I do manual test in browser everything works fine.

I receive exception produced by getByText():

> Unable to find an element with the text: /Tasty Metal Keyboard/i. This
>   could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this
>   case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your
>   matcher more flexible.

```
    /** import React, mockAxios etc. */
    const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);


    const inputRootPath = document.createElement('input');
    inputRootPath.id = 'rootPath';
    inputRootPath.hidden = true;
    inputRootPath.value = 'http://localhost/';


    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} ui komponent
     * @param {*} param { initialState, store }
     */
    export function renderWithRedux(
        ui,
        { initialState, store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(middleware)) } = {},
    ) {
        return {
            ...render(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    {ui}
                </Provider>,
                { container: document.body.appendChild(inputRootPath) }
            ),
            store,
        };
    }


       test('should render annex list', async () => {

const agBuilder = () => {
        return {
            ID: faker.random.number(),
            NM: faker.commerce.productName(),

        };
    };


    const agreements = [agBuilder(), agBuilder(), agBuilder(), agBuilder()];



     mockAxios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { ANLST: agreements } });

            const { getByText, } = await renderWithRedux(<ConnectedAgreements />);

            const optionRE = new RegExp(`${agreements[0].NM}`, 'i');
            expect(getByText(optionRE)).toBeInTheDocument();

            mockAxios.post.mockClear();
        });
```

**mocks**/axios.js

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} }),
    post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} }),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It turns out that after some code refactor I have another reducer which takes dispatch action invoked in CDM. It destructure axios response so my test code should have:

```
mockAxios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { ANLST: agreements, CLS: {}, EXLDT: {} } });
```

Missing CLS and EXLDT properties casue test fail. Jest however doesn't print error that something is missing or undefined ¯_(ツ)_/¯ . Exception produced by getByText() was misleading.